# How to achieve a desired angle with pipe fittings

Tags: pipe

I want to come out the back of a spigot at a 90 degree angle - e.g. from this

[Hose bib](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MA9F8RE),

To this

[Brass elbow](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004XUKSF0)

However, when you screw the two all the way together, you'll end up with a (*seemingly?*) arbitrarily oriented elbow. That is, say for example a pipe was coming up from the bottom, but when you screwed the elbow to the spigot the elbow ended up pointing up, which wouldn't work.

It would seem reasonable to be able to control the direction that you come out,

**How would you do this?**

Comment: You don't tighten the joint to the point where it will not turn more. If you have sealed the threads properly, it will be leak free even if it is not tightened are far as it will go. Back off until you get the orientation you want, turn on the water and see if it leaks. It seems to me that modern tapered threaded nipples and other fittings that I get from the big box nowadays are not as well made as I remember from decades ago. The last four threaded connections I made seeped for a few days before sealing. I used pipe dope on two washer connections and Teflon tape plus dope on outside faucets.

Comment: You have a range between too loose(leaks)  and too tight(snap pipe).  Direction you want will be in this range.

Comment: I agree with @Jim Stewart  you might need to put fresh tape on the fitting but not cranking down until metal on metal will usually seal long before locking up.